# Please standardise the edit-box UI across the SE sites, see eg the hyperlink icon

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, design

Above the box where I'm typing this text there is a menu bar.  The menu bar here has a different icon for hyperlink than the menu bar on (for example) [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).  Here a globe with an arrow is used.  There a chain is used.

Some screenshot examples:

> [image]

Whereas for UX.SE and some other sites, it's:

> [image]

Comment: I should add, there are some style differences.  The icon for Image is slightly different.  The question mark is different.  But those are, I guess, okay.  It's just odd to have a standard menu bar that is different across different sites.  It's a bit confusing if you use different SE sites.

Comment: I'm confused by this. I would have assumed StackExchange sites would just use default CKEditor icons here, not bespoke ones for each site. Strange.